# From MySQL to IndexedDB with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I've posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638999/from-mysql-to-indexeddb) a few days ago, but I'm not sure I exposed properly my problem, so I'd like to expose it in another way.
I want to send the content of MySQL database into an IndexedDB database.
I have this, on the PHP side:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", $mypassword, $myDB);
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$to_encode = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $to_encode[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($to_encode);

mysqli_close($con);
```

and on the javascript side:

```
$.getJSON('./php/database.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            // Populate the IndexedDB database here     
    });
});
```

I'm pretty new to development and especially with IndexedDB so I have a hard time to understand the process. I'm not even sure if it's possible to do what I want.
Can somebody help please ?

Comment: At least, is it something possible, or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your database, is hard to give you a code that "just works".

I suggest you take a look at the [following example](https://gist.github.com/BigstickCarpet/a0d6389a5d0e3a24814b) which shows you how to use the native IndexedDB API.

Also, I suggest you (if you want to make it easier) to use a library to manage IndexedDB. For example [Dexie](http://dexie.org).

Just remember that first, you have to create a Schema which is the representation of your data (in mysql, the structure of the table) then once your schema is created, you can start adding data to the IndexedDB.

I hope it helps

Comment: The database (MySQL) has 30 columns and 297 rows, so there is a lot of stuff to show here and that's why I tried to be straight to the point. The reason I'm asking the question is because when I use the "$.getJSON" statement I have a big huge JSON object but I don't know what to do with that when it's time to use it with IndexedDB.

Comment: Well, as I said in the response, first you have to create the schema. You have to manually write that as your json response will contain the rows but not the schema.
Once the schema is created, you'll be able to insert all your rows (the json that you got) but it has to be properly formatted according to the IndexedDB library that you use.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll try that :)